# Push data to out side async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I still do not handle well the asynchronous functions, I have an array of items, and I'm trying to for each item calculate some values and push to another array outside of the async function. Then I want to make some statistics calculation and send to front end. It's server side, nodejs handler, my code:

```
exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {

  function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
  }

  function statistics(values) {
    var sum = math.sum(values);
    var max = math.max(values);
    var min = math.min(values);
    var stddev = math.std(values);
    var mean = math.mean(values);
    var count = values.length;
  }

  plugin.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/statistics/{orgId}/layout/{layoutId}',
    config: {
      pre: [
        authorize(hasRole(['OPERATIONAL', 'STRATEGIC', 'LOP', 'TACTICAL']))
      ],
      handler: function (request, reply) {

        Category.find()
        .where('organization')
        .equals(request.params.orgId)
        .exec(function (err, categories) {

          var weight = [];
          var price = [];
          var volume = [];
          var thisAR = [];

          if (err || categories === null) {
            return reply(Boom.badRequest('Categoria inexistente'));
          } else {

            Location.findById(request.params.layoutId)
            .exec(function (err, layout) {
              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }

              var searchItems = function searchItems(category, next) {

                Item.find()
                .where('category')
                .equals(category._id)
                .exec(function (err, items) {

                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    var valuesToCalculate = [];
                    var itemsFiltered = [];
                    _.forEach(items, function(item) {
                      if(item.location && item.location !== null) {
                        if(isInArray(item.location.toString(), layout.contents)) {
                          itemsFiltered.push(item);
                        }
                      }
                    });
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.weight);
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.price);
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.volume);
                    next(valuesToCalculate);
                  }
                });
              }

              var onFinish = function onFinish(value, err) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(value);
                thisAR.push.apply(value);
              }

              async.each(categories, searchItems, onFinish);
              console.log(thisAR);
              //var arrays = [statistics(weight), statistics(price), statistics(volume)];
              //return arrays;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  next();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things stand out to me about this. First, you only call reply if there is an err or categories is null. Also, you are attempting to pass a non null value to an async.each callback. According to this: https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback, "if no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument". I think you may misunderstand how the onFinish callback works with async.each.. it is not called for each item, it is called when *all* of  the iterator functions have completed. So, rather than pushing items onto thisAR in onFinish, you should do so inside searchItems. I think this should work:

```
exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {

  function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
  }

  function statistics(values) {
    var sum = math.sum(values);
    var max = math.max(values);
    var min = math.min(values);
    var stddev = math.std(values);
    var mean = math.mean(values);
    var count = values.length;
  }

  plugin.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/statistics/{orgId}/layout/{layoutId}',
    config: {
      pre: [
        authorize(hasRole(['OPERATIONAL', 'STRATEGIC', 'LOP', 'TACTICAL']))
      ],
      handler: function (request, reply) {

        Category.find()
        .where('organization')
        .equals(request.params.orgId)
        .exec(function (err, categories) {

          var weight = [];
          var price = [];
          var volume = [];
          var thisAR = [];

          if (err || categories === null) {
            return reply(Boom.badRequest('Categoria inexistente'));
          } else {

            Location.findById(request.params.layoutId)
            .exec(function (err, layout) {
              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }

              var searchItems = function searchItems(category, next) {

                Item.find()
                .where('category')
                .equals(category._id)
                .exec(function (err, items) {

                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    var valuesToCalculate = [];
                    var itemsFiltered = [];
                    _.forEach(items, function(item) {
                      if(item.location && item.location !== null) {
                        if(isInArray(item.location.toString(), layout.contents)) {
                          itemsFiltered.push(item);
                        }
                      }
                    });
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.weight);
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.price);
                    valuesToCalculate.push(itemsFiltered.length * category.data.volume);
                    thisAR.push.apply(valuesToCalculate);
                  }
                  next(err);
                });
              }

              var onFinish = function onFinish(err) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(thisAR);
                // call reply here
              }

              async.each(categories, searchItems, onFinish);
              console.log(thisAR);
              //var arrays = [statistics(weight), statistics(price), statistics(volume)];
              //return arrays;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  next();
};
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeAtkins for the replay, yes I totally misunderstood what onFinish function do. I've tried what you say, but the console.log in the onFinish function is empty. What I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure. side note: I moved the call to next out of the `else` body and added a the err as an argument to next, for better error handling. are you not seeing any console messages at all?

Comment: also are you sure items is not empty?

Comment: With the comment from @brian baker, it's work perfect. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since I'm new but it seems that just removing the `.apply` in `thisAR.push.apply(valuesToCalculate);` will return a full array to your console.log.